# lock element to the SVG element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, svg

I have the following SVG of a phone:

```
<svg width="897px" height="452px" viewBox="0 0 897 452" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
    <g id="iphone" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup" stroke="#7E89A3" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <path d="M130,257.964 C130,266.797 122.809,273.956 113.938,273.956 L16.063,273.956 C7.192,273.956 0.001,266.797 0.001,257.964 L0.001,16.073 C0.001,7.24 7.192,0.081 16.063,0.081 L113.938,0.081 C122.809,0.081 130,7.24 130,16.073 L130,257.964 L130,257.964 Z"
              id="bezel" stroke-width="2" fill="white" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
        <rect id="screen" fill="#ddd"
              sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" x="9" y="36" width="111.93" height="199.084"></rect>
        <path d="M77,25.746 C77,26.381 76.561,26.893 76.02,26.893 L55.918,26.893 C55.376,26.893 54.938,26.38 54.938,25.746 L54.938,23.166 C54.938,22.531 55.377,22.019 55.918,22.019 L76.02,22.019 C76.561,22.019 77,22.532 77,23.166 L77,25.746 L77,25.746 Z" id="speaker"
              sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
        <circle id="camera" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" cx="66" cy="12" r="3"></circle>
        <ellipse id="lock" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" cx="65.04" cy="254.001" rx="10.04" ry="10.001"></ellipse>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Which looks like following:

[image]

I will be using AngularJS to dynamically generate `<ul>` with elements on the phone screen, where generated elements will be interactive (users will be able to e.g. click on them).

The challenge however is, how to lock the size of my `div` element (which will hold the `ul` element), so that it always has the size of the screen? I want this phone to be center aligned on my page, but as far as I know, the SVG size will adapt to the actual window size.

Is there a way how to dynamically poisition my `div` element to be only on the phone's screen?

P.S. I can see that my SVG contains element with id `screen` so maybe somehow detect the position of this element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend placing an absolutely positioned `div` over the SVG element. You can calculate the dimensions of the screen image by using the `getBoundingClientRect()` method. The code is simple:

```
var ui = document.getElementById("ui");
var screen = document.getElementById("screen");
var dimensions = screen.getBoundingClientRect();

ui.style.left = dimensions.left + "px";
ui.style.top = dimensions.top + "px";
ui.style.width = dimensions.width + "px";
ui.style.height = dimensions.height + "px";
```

[image]

You can see a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/hxe9nb3n/

Answer (score 0):

For a start it doesn't have to adapt to the size of the window. That behaviour is under your control.

Alternatively, you can embed HTML inside an SVG using the `<foreignObject>` element.  That way the embedded HTML will adapt to whatever size the SVG becomes.  There are many examples of how to do that in SO.